# Uncaught exception thrown after moving my website to localhost

Tags: 7, database, importing-exporting

My website works right on server, I took a backup from database and public_html in order to have a copy of my webstie in localhost.

I imported the database but it reported an error, some thing was wrong with content of  `cache_views` table, so I emptied this table and database successfully imported. I replaced public_html with the old one and configured `settings.php`. but it doesn't work, it reports this error :

**Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception.**

Original

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: SELECT s.lid, t.translation, s.version FROM {locales_source} s LEFT JOIN {locales_target} t ON s.lid = t.lid AND t.language = :language WHERE s.source = :source AND s.context = :context AND s.textgroup = &#039;default&#039;; Array ( [:language] =&gt; fa [:source] =&gt; Makes the view results available as a context for use in Panels and other applications. [:context] =&gt; ) in locale() (line 684 of C:\xampp\htdocs\test\modules\locale\locale.module).
```

Additional:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: INSERT INTO {watchdog} (uid, type, message, variables, severity, link, location, referer, hostname, timestamp) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] =&gt; 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] =&gt; php [:db_insert_placeholder_2] =&gt; %type: !message in %function (line %line of %file). [:db_insert_placeholder_3] =&gt; a:6:{s:5:&quot;%type&quot;;s:12:&quot;PDOException&quot;;s:8:&quot;!message&quot;;s:455:&quot;SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: SELECT s.lid, t.translation, s.version FROM {locales_source} s LEFT JOIN {locales_target} t ON s.lid = t.lid AND t.language = :language WHERE s.source = :source AND s.context = :context AND s.textgroup = &amp;#039;default&amp;#039;; Array ( [:language] =&amp;gt; fa [:source] =&amp;gt; Makes the view results available as a context for use in Panels and other applications. [:context] =&amp;gt; ) &quot;;s:9:&quot;%function&quot;;s:8:&quot;locale()&quot;;s:5:&quot;%file&quot;;s:52:&quot;C:\xampp\htdocs\test\modules\locale\locale.module&quot;;s:5:&quot;%line&quot;;i:684;s:14:&quot;severity_level&quot;;i:3;} [:db_insert_placeholder_4] =&gt; 3 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] =&gt; [:db_insert_placeholder_6] =&gt; h t t p://localhost:81/test/ [:db_insert_placeholder_7] =&gt; [:db_insert_placeholder_8] =&gt; 127.0.0.1 [:db_insert_placeholder_9] =&gt; 1389935326 ) in dblog_watchdog() (line 154 of C:\xampp\htdocs\test\modules\dblog\dblog.module).
```

Comment: Try restarting mysql on your local machine and double check if you have the right connection details in settings.php

Comment: @SumeetPareek I do have right connection details in settings.php, this is the same settings that was working on older version of website. I also restarted mysql and it didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem this way: set max_allowed_packet = 4M to the file php.ini

Comment: Thanks sooooooo much it worked :) . in fact it is in `my.ini` not `php.ini` . thanks again

Comment: my.cnf for me :)